# does table order affect mysql order

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm trying to optimize a mysql data base query and have run into a result that I do not really understand, hence would appreciate some hints on what is going on here.

We have a database with 4 tables, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

Please note that the database as presented here is merely snippet of the full database which is set up by a third party software and not in our control to change.

The tables are

```
mysql> show create table a;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
   `_oid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `_last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT
   `val` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`_oid`),
   CONSTRAINT `a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`_oid`) REFERENC
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `_oid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_oid`),
  CONSTRAINT `b_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`_oid`) REFERENCE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `c`(
   `_oid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
   `po` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
   `pm` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`_oid`),
   KEY `po` (`po`), 
   KEY `pm` (`pm`), 
   CONSTRAINT `c_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`_oid`) REFERENC
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `d` (
   `_oid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`_oid`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `d_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`_oid`) REFERENC
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

table `c` here is used to define the the preferred rows in table `a` and `b`, whilst table `d` is used to connect rows in `a` and `b` to rows in `c`. Hence in terms of rows table `d` has by far the most rows (the number of rows in `d` is equal to the summed number of rows in `a` and `b`).

As it turns out the order one lists the tables to retrieve rows from has an impact on the execution time to handle a query. Consider the query

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT a.val, b.ref, dc.id FROM d da, c, d dc, b, d db, a 
    -> WHERE c._oid=dc._oid AND a._oid=da._oid AND b._oid=db._oid AND db.id=c.pm AND da.id=c.po AND a._last_modified >= "2022-02-15 20:00:00";
+-----+-----+----+
| val | ref | id |
+-----+-----+----+
|   1 |   3 | q  |
|   2 |   4 | l  |
+-----+-----+----+
2 rows in set (0.85 sec)
```

If I however move the first table listed in the table list on the FROM clause to be the last, the execution time increases by almost a factor 3.

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT a.val, b.ref, dc.id FROM c, d dc, b, d db, a, d da 
    ->  WHERE c._oid=dc._oid AND a._oid=da._oid AND b._oid=db._oid AND db.id=c.pm AND da.id=c.po AND a._last_modified >= "2022-02-15 20:00:00";
+------+-----+----+
| val  | ref | id |
+------+-----+----+
| 1    |   3 | q  | 
| 2    |   4 | l  | 
+------+-----+----+
2 rows in set (2.49 sec)
```

Examining what the optimizer does under the hood I see that simply rearrangement of the table list affects how the query is executed explaining the difference in execution time.

```
 mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT a.val, b.ref, dc.id FROM d da, c, d dc, b, d db, a 
     -> WHERE c._oid=dc._oid AND a._oid=da._oid AND b._oid=db._oid AND db.id=c.pm AND da.id=c.po AND a._last_modified >= "2022-02-15 20:00:00";
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref          | rows  | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL    | PRIMARY,po,pm | NULL     | NULL    | NULL         | 39392 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | da    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id    | id       | 767     | data.c.po    |     1 | Using index     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | data.da._oid |     1 | Using where     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dc    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | data.c._oid  |     1 |                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | db    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id    | id       | 767     | data.c.pm    |     1 | Using index     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | data.dB._oid |     1 |                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT a.val, b.ref, dc.id FROM c, d dc, b, d db, a, d da 
     -> WHERE c._oid=dc._oid AND a._oid=da._oid AND b._oid=db._oid AND db.id=c.pm AND da.id=c.po AND a._last_modified >= "2022-02-15 20:00:00";
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref          | rows  | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL    | PRIMARY,po,pm | NULL     | NULL    | NULL         | 39392 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dc    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | data.c._oid  |     1 |                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | db    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id    | id       | 767     | data.c.pm    |     1 | Using index     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | data.db._oid |     1 |                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | da    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id    | id       | 767     | data.c.po    |     1 | Using index     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | data.da._oid |     1 | Using where     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What I'm struggling to understand here is why the rearrangement of the table list so that I can better than current trial-and-error approach optimize my queries. Any insight and/or links to where I can read up on this is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you write your query using the `join` syntax instead of `from a, b, c, d`? Also, using a, b, c and d makes it difficult to understand the purpose of tables.

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Also, you seem to be saying that `d` is a many-many table; in which case I don't understand why you're joining with `d` three times in your query? It should be referenced just once.

Comment: MySQL is free in tables scanning order selection. If you want MySQL to scan the tables in definite order then use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` modifier. But remember - if your data statistic is not too old and inaccurate then MySQL selects optimal scanning order in most cases... PS. Outer joins are straight joins hiddenly.

Comment: @Akina Yes I understand that that "MySQL is free in tables scanning order selection" but am trying to understand why the scanning order differ here. Are you trying to say that the implicit join translates into an outer join?

Comment: What is "implicit join"? I know inner (including cross) and outer joins only. Comma-style join is CROSS JOIN (but comma-style join has less priority than cross join).

Comment: *but am trying to understand why the scanning order differ here.* I think that the plans cost difference calculated from the tables statistic is less than analysis accuracy, and both plans have equal cost from MySQL looking point. So it selects one of them indefinitely (this is like ORDER BY non_unique_expression LIMIT 1).

Comment: @Akina, "implicit join" if I understand it correctly is when you implicitly joins two tables in the WHERE clause rather than explicitly join them in the FROM clause, e.g. `FROM a, b WHERE a.val = b.val AND <criteria>`  vs. `FROM a JOIN b ON a.val=b.val WHERE <criteria>` (the implicit join being deprecated as pointed out by @Stu).

Comment: @SalmanA the purpose of the tables are not relevant for the question (they are reduced from a larger database, used by a third party software, to the minimum required model required to demonstrate my question, apologies if the naming disturbs you). The three joins with table `d` are required as the values are not the same, i.e. `da._oid != db._oid != dc._oid`. Basically table `c` is used to identify the rows to use in `da` and `db` which are then used to identify the rows to use in `a` and `b`

Answer (score 1):

- 4 tables with the same `PRIMARY KEY(_oid)`; can't the tables be combined into a single table.
- Please use the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax instead of "commajoin".  (And I reordered the tables so that I could follow them in the order that they will be processed.)

  ```
  SELECT  DISTINCT a.val, b.ref, dc.id
    FROM       a
    JOIN  d AS da  ON a._oid=da._oid
    JOIN       c   ON da.id=c.po
    JOIN  d AS dc  ON c._oid=dc._oid
    JOIN  d AS db  ON db.id=c.pm
    JOIN       b   ON b._oid=db._oid
   WHERE  a._last_modified >= "2022-02-15 20:00:00";
  ```
- Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` because it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  In particular, it provides the indexes.
- These indexes may help with performance:

  ```
  a:  INDEX(_last_modified, _oid, val)
  b:  INDEX(_oid,  ref)
  c:  INDEX(po,  _oid, pm)
  d:  INDEX(_oid)
  d:  INDEX(id)
  ```

Comment: Putting a timestamp as the first column in a compound index is rarely a good idea. If you used `(_oid, _last_modified, val)` then the index would be in the same order as the index it's being joined with.  (Admittedly, it does all depend on cardinality / data behaviour, but in my experience it's extremely rare that timestamp first makes sense.)

Comment: @MatBailie - I usually agree that a "range" value should not be first in an index.  However, since it is the only thing in `WHERE`, doing so is the only change to avoid a full table scan for the "first" table.  Of course, if that range spans most of the table, the index will not be used, and the table will be scanned anyway.

Comment: @RickJames, 1. No the tables can not be joined, they all contain different information and the linking of rows between the tables do change as more information becomes available (and the third party software populating the database would not be able to use) 2. Appologies for the "commajoin" an thanks for the `JOIN` syntax version 3. the post is updated 4. Sorry we do not have permission to change the database (including adding indexes).

Comment: No add index?  Rather draconian!